# How can I use a variable as a key in a new JS hashtable

Tags: javascript

Is there a way in javascript that I can use variables in new hashtables as keys

example

```
var key1 = "test1";
var key2 = "test2";

var table = { key1: true, key2: true };
```

But I would like the table to end up being

```
{ test1: true, test2: true }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use it by following example:

```
var key1 = "test1",
  key2 = "test2",
  table = {};

table[ key1 ] = true;
table[ key2 ] = true;

console.log( table ); // { test1: true, test2: true }
```

See jsFiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/antyrat/nwRnc/).

So accessing them would be like

```
console.log( table.test1 );
```

or

```
console.log( table[ key1 ] );
```

or

```
console.log( table[ "test1" ] );
```

Comment: I understand that it can be done this way, but I was wondering if there was a more inline method

Comment: @Wryte No, there is no inline method for this

Comment: You might get close by defining some kind of zipping or converting function: `zipKeys([[key1, key2], [true, true]])` or `toHashTable([[key1, true], [key2, true]])`. Or, with a chainable API like underscore, you can mixin a chainable setter function and get something like `var table = _.chain({}).set(key1, true).set(key2, true).value()`.